# Netbeans and SVN UUID problem

Tags: svn, netbeans

I created a project in Netbeans. Than I imported the directory to SVN. I can check out the project, but when I try to commit I get this error : Repository UUID 'XXXXX..' doesn't match expected UUID 'xxx....' I'm new to SVN and I'm not sure why this is happening.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This usually occurs for two reasons.

- The repository you checked out from has had a significant change in form of a dump & load done to it since you checked out and made changes.
- You're checking out from a read-only copy (svnsync) and then your commit is occurring via a proxy-pass through on the read-only server to the read/write server and the read-only server does not have the UUID as the read/write server.

Without more detail about your Subversion setup, this one will be hard to get an answer with.  If you or your team don't have control of the Subversion server, get with who ever does and see if they can help you with more information.