# import into repository option disabled in Netbeans on Ubuntu

Tags: svn, netbeans, ubuntu-10.04

I have created SVN repository on Ubuntu 10.04. I manually imported a project to repository and then checkout it in Netbeans and it works fine. Now I have created a new project in Netbeans and I would like to import it into repository using Netbeans Import Into Repository feature  (rather than manually) but it is grey out (can't click on it). Not sure why is that like this.

Comment: Did you try to click back and try again? Do you have any .svn folders within your project?

Comment: I haven't found any .svn folders in this project directory

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you do not have any .svn folders within the (new) project. Also, close NetBeans, delete %NetBeans_User_Dir%\var\cache and try again after starting NetBeans.

Edit: Looks like [this is a randomly occurring bug](http://netbeans.org/projects/versioncontrol/lists/issues/archive/2010-07/message/34). Can you try what he/she suggests?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu as I mentioned.

Comment: Edited my answer to remove the Windows path.

Comment: Thanks, but when I delete cache will this change any settings I have set in Netbeans

Comment: You can safely delete it. You will only lose some indexed data. It will take a bit longer to start, that is all.

Comment: I updated my answer - it may be a bug - can you try what they are suggesting? That is,  try  to check out at least one project from any repository (so that repository URL is saved by Netbeans), and then try Import option.

Comment: Yes I have seen this bug and I have checked out the manually added project (as described in question) and it didn't work.

Comment: Just confirming: only your "Repository URL" is grayed out, isn't it? Can you get a screenshot?

Comment: Is there other way to add it to repository? If I remember correctly I tried to import new project into svn manually from netbeans directory using the command line and then when I was trying to commit it was giving UUID error when trying to commit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238286/netbeans-and-svn-uuid-problem

Comment: Only checkout and commit url's are enabled. The remaining url's are all grey out.

Comment: I finally imported it, however not using Import Into Repository, but by creating a project in Netbeans, than importing manually the project directory to SVN, deleting Netbeans project, deleting cache folder as you previously suggested and then opening Netbeans and check out the project from the repository.